# Zend2: Outputting a single form element if its a radio button list?

Tags: zend-framework2

I have a radio button list with three options: daily, monthly, weekly. I want a way to access each one individually. For example:

```
echo $this->formElement($form->get('iteration'));
```

Will print out all three values, with their labels:

```
[ ] daily
[ ] monthly
[ ] weekly
```

I want a way to iterate over all the elements. Something like this:

```
foreach ($this->formElements($form->get('iteration') as $element)  {
    echo $this->formElement($element); 
}
```

But that doens't work. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're using the `Zend\Form\Element\Radio` form element with multiple options, you can iterate over the options like this:

```
foreach ($form->get('iteration')->getValueOptions() as $option) {
    ...
}
```

But if you want to output the options separately, you'd need to create multiple `Zend\Form\Element\Radio`'s.